# How to do a calculation with DateTime.Now()

Tags: c#, datetime

this question may seem simple to some, but it's got my mind baffled completely - I'm a bit of a newbie to C#.

**The set-up:**

Trying to do a calculation with `DateTime.Now()` for an  "Alarm" based application.

**The problem:**

I have one `label`, which displays the current time.
I have one `Masked Text box`, which accepts user inputs when he/she sets the alarm.

I'm trying to do a calculation, whereby I'll add another `label` displaying the time a person still has left to sleep.

Which, conceptually, should look something like

```
TimeLeftToSleep(lbl) = CurrentAlarmTime-DateTime.Now()
```

It keeps giving an error though, tried parsing, but I can't seem to get it to work the error it produces is a long the lines of:

```
Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DateTime'.
```

Comment: `CurrentAlarmTime` is a string....

Comment: Next time, please read your error messages **more carefully**.

Comment: Try posting the actual code

Answer (score 1):

The `TextBox.Text` provides a string, you should first parse it to a `DateTime` to do any calculation with it.

```
DateTime result;

if (DateTime.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out result))
{
    // the delta between two datetimes is a timespan.
    TimeSpan delta = result - DateTime.Now;

    // show the timespan within the label.
    TimeLeftToSleep.Text = delta.ToString();
}
else
{
    // the textbox doesn't contain a valid datetime.
}
```

For more info on TimeSpan: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx
And here for DateTime.TryParse method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Tried this as well, same error as Sasse's suggestion it can't convert labels to strings.

Comment: You might try the `Text` property of the label. _Looks like a school assignment_  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Your CurrentAlarmTime must be type of DateTime. DateTime has numbers of constructors and Parse methods, that should not be a problem.

Also `DateTime.Now` is a property, get rid of the parentheses.

I would do something like this:

```
(CurrentAlarmTime - DateTime.Now).Ticks
```

and use ticks value to get a TimeSpan.

Comment: DateTime - DateTime is already a TimeSpan, so there's no need to get ticks and then translate ticks to a TimeSpan again.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `CurrentAlarmTime` is a string - I assume this is the text the user entered. In order to perform date mathematics on this value, you need to first turn it into a DateTime using the [DateTime.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
var parsedCurrentAlarmTime = DateTime.Parse(CurrentAlarmTime);
```

Comment: So I've tried what you've posted and it doesn't allow me to convert from a label to string - I know I'm probably leaving out something silly, but yeah... This error occurs: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' to 'string'. As I've mentioned the value stored in the "CurrentAlarm" label is causing problems, should I perhaps remove that label and add a text box?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your CurrentAlarmTime is a string. You can use DateTime.Parse to get a DateTime from it, then your subtraction should work (and result in a TimeSpan object).

Also, DateTime.Now is a property, not a method. You do not need to (and shouldn't) write () after it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code. DateTime.Now is a property, so remove the parentheses. Your CurrentAlarmTime is of type "string" so you need to convert it to a DateTime first.

Look at the following example (it's not complete and not very good but should give you an idea of what you should do):

Edited since user don't have two textboxes.

```
int hour = 0;
int minute = 0;

try
{
    hour = int.Parse(this.AlarmTextBox.Text.Split(':').First());
    minute = int.Parse(this.AlarmTextBox.Text.Split(':').Last());
}
catch
{
}

var currentAlarmTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(hour).AddMinutes(minute);
var timeLeftToSleep = currentAlarmTime - DateTime.Now;

this.timeLeftToSleepLabel.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", timeLeftToSleep.TotalHours, timeLeftToSleep.Minutes);
```

Comment: Hmmm.. The problem is that my values are stored in labels which already contain both the hours and minutes so I don't understand why I'd need to create two separate variables for minutes and hours as both those values are stored in label and a Masked Text box, they're like two different items.

Comment: I don't understand exacly what you mean, but I've updated my answer to get both hours and minutes from one textbox. If you can get the values in a better way then do that instead, my answer is more a way to let you see how it can be done so that you can do in your specific case. =)

Comment: Maybe you should do something like maskedTextBox.Text.Substring(0,2) and maskedTextBox.Text.Substring(2, 2) to get hour and minute.

Comment: Appreciate the help, don't get me wrong - I know the fault is on my side and I can't figure out how to correct it, but it's okay - I'll struggle on valiantly :D

Comment: If you can't convert a Label to string you are missing that it's not the Label you want but it's text. Like "new DateTime(myLabel.Text);". A Label is a control that has several properties, but you're only intrested in the "Text" property.

Answer (score -1):

You should use DateTime class method Subtract as:

```
var date2 = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " 10:00");
System.TimeSpan diff1 = date2.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: I get that *all* the time